# How to create an animation which cycles through a series of matpyplot.pyplot imshows

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, imshow

I would like to convert the following code into an animation which cycles through the x values rather than just returning one x value like it currently does.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sliceplot(file_glob,xslice):
    """User inputs location of binary data file
    and single slice of x axis is returned as plot"""

    data=np.fromfile(file_glob,dtype=np.float32)
    data=data.reshape((400,400,400))
    plt.imshow(data[xslice,:,:])
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.show()
```

I have tried following this example but can't seem to translate it into what I need: http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/dynamic_image.html

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what you like to do?  My example below -- based on [this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/dynamic_image.html) example -- is using some dummy-image from the function `generate_image`, defined in the script.  From what I understand of your question you would rather load a new file for every iteration, which can be done by replacing the functionality of `generate_image`.  You should probably use an array of file_names instead of the array with the data-matrices as I did here, but for transparency I did it this way (however it is very unefficient for large data-sets!).

Moreover I also added two extra arguments to the `FuncAnimation`-call, to 1) make sure it stops when you're out of images (with `frames=len(images)`) and 2) `fargs=[images, ]` to pass the image array into the function.  You can read more [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html).

Also note that

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def generate_image(n):
    def f(x, y):
        return np.sin(x) + np.cos(y)
    imgs = []
    x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 120)
    y = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100).reshape(-1, 1)
    for i in range(n):
        x += np.pi / 15.
        y += np.pi / 20.
        imgs.append(f(x, y))
    return imgs


images = generate_image(100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)    
im = ax.imshow(images[0], cmap=plt.get_cmap('coolwarm'), animated=True)

def updatefig(i, my_arg):
    im.set_array(my_arg[i])
    return im,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updatefig, frames=len(images), fargs=[images, ], interval=50, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

An example of the file-name loader would be something like

```
def load_my_file(filename):
    # load your file!
    ...
    return loaded_array

file_names = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3']

def updatefig(i, my_arg):
    # load file into an array
    data = load_my_file(my_arg[i])  # <<---- load the file in whatever way you like
    im.set_array(data)
    return im,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updatefig, frames=len(file_names), fargs=[file_names, ], interval=50, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Hope it helps!